# can I tell google maps to avoid motorways?

Tags: google-maps

So, my question is

Is there any way for me to tell google maps, to avoid motorways?

**Edit**

I'll add some screenshots to show why the currently suggested answer doesn't seem to apply.

Say I search for my destination

[image]

I see no blue circle

I can tap "Get Directions" then I get this screen

So I see the icons for car, bus, cycling, walking.

Say I tap the bottom right three dots. Then it just says  "Reverse start & end"

[image]

If I tap the car, then I  get two options. Get Directions, or Navigate.

There's no 3 dots in the top right or anywhere,  with a "route options" option, that the suggested answer mentions.

I'm not seeing the option to avoid motorways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using advice concerning route plotting avoiding motorways etc. i couldnt find the suggested thing to be looking for.
i did however find out how to do it.
open maps, choose location. tap directions, then start.
along the bottom there is now a symbol of a 2 pronged arrow one side is a broken arrow. tap here and you will get the options on what you want to avoid :)

Answer (score 2):

The following seems to be the answer though I haven't put it in practise yet.

in google maps, choose navigation, then in the bottom right there are 3 horizontal bars, then  it has options of "routes and alternatives, directions list, layers, turn off voice, exit navigation, more".  Choose "routes and alternatives"

Then it has 4 buttons..

A button with a blue arrow,

A button with 2 cogs

A button with arrows pointing to what looks like a raindrop.

A button with 3 dots with 3 horizontal bars alongside the dots.

Click the button with 2 cogs.

Then it says Route options.  Avoid motorways.   Avoid toll roads.  You can choose "Avoid Motorways".

I'll include some pics when I can.

Answer (score 1):

Highways can be avoided ( as also tolls)

Maps app help gives the way for it (search for *avoid Motorways* in app help

> - Open the Google Maps app Google Maps.
> - Search for your destination or tap it on the map.
> - In the bottom right, tap the blue circle. It'll show a car, bus, bike, taxi, or person walking.
> - At the top, tap Drive .
> - In the top right, tap More three vertical dots and then Route options.
>   Tap Avoid tolls or Avoid highways.

---

Post your edit, here are the screen shots from [Google Maps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps) version `9.33.1`

Steps 1 and 2 are obvious

**Step 3** showing the blue circle

[image]

**Step 3(a)** ( not mentioned separately , perhaps app help needs updating)-choosing the start point and mode of travel

[image]

**Step 4 (by 3 button menu on to right) and 5 (sub options of route options)**

[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you mean "Click Directions Directions".  And  What does it mean  "Click points on the map"?   Can you try it yourself, since you post it as an answer?

Comment: That was for *web* meaning if you are you using a web browser. Will delete that to remove confusion. I have linked the source too

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is how I did it.

1. Open Google Maps.
2. Search destination
3. Tap blue bar at bottom which says "directions"
4. put in starting address in upper bar
5. Tap the 3 dots to the right
6. Look down and locate and top "Route Options"
7. Check Avoid Highways.
8. Click "Done"

Comment: By the way,  2. tap blue bar that says "directions" not destinations.